# Jquery .text() with php foreach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to show in a div dynamically some content. 
This content, come from a function i have in php.

Any ideas how can i do this?

HTML:

```
 <div class="creativeSecondField">
      <h1 class="secondFieldTitle"></h1>
      <div class="secondFieldContent"></div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".creativeSecondField > div.secondFieldContent").text(""+
    <?php
    $info+this.id = $this->sqlCategories+this.id;
    foreach ( $info+this.id as $valuesinfo+this.id )
    {
    echo $valuesinfo+this.id['designation_en'];
    }
    ?>
+"");
```

Comment: did this code, actually work for you?

Comment: @true not really :( but i dont know what is wrong

Comment: PHP runs on the server when the page is being created. It can't update the page dynamically after it has been sent to the browser.

Comment: @Barmar but this jquery function it is working when the document is ready

Comment: PHP can't access Javascript variables like `this`. You need to understand the relationship between PHP and Javascript.

Comment: There's no way it can work. `this.id` is a PHP syntax error.

Comment: @Barmar uhmm..and if i create a var something = this.id; and pass it to php? this way will work?

Comment: suggest starting over by explaining higher level of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Yes, you need to use AJAX to send Javascript values to PHP, and get the result back to update the DOM.

Comment: Try to solve it first with only PHP, no javascript whatsoever. Then add the AJAX functionality (check `jquery.ajax` in the jquery docs). 
Notice how for your PHP-only solution you need to refresh to get your div updated with new/extra results.

Answer (score 1):

First create a php page which return a dynamic content like

getContent.php

```
<?php
echo "hello";
?>
```

after that on that page where you want to display the dynamic content using jquery do like this

```
    <div class="creativeSecondField">
          <h1 class="secondFieldTitle"></h1>
          <div class="secondFieldContent"></div>
    </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".secondFieldTitle").load("getContent.php");
});
</script>
```

use it thank you....